# How to make consistent display of image in cell in tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have an image in a custom cell (called "StoryCell"), the reference to which is in a Realm database and which I am loading up in the CellForRowAt with the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {   

 ....

let story = stories?[indexPath.row]

if story?.storyImage.isEmpty == true {

        print("Do nothing")
    } else {

        let path = getDocumentDirectory().appendingPathComponent(story!.storyImage)

        do {
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: path)
            let retrievedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            cell.storyImage.image = retrievedImage

        } catch {

            print("Error retrieving image: \(error)")

        }
    }

    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

However, whenever I am adding a new table item, after the eighth time the display of the images becomes inconsistent i.e. the first picture repeats on the eighth line. I know this is connected with the 'reuse' nature of cells in tableviews and have tried to resolve it using the 'if' statement in my code above, and also by 'reloading' the tableview data when the new item is added:

```
@IBAction func addStoryButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let newStory = Story()

        newStory.dateCreated = Date()

        self.save(story: newStory)

  self.storiesTableView.reloadData()
}
```

However, I still get the same behaviour. Thanks in advance for any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full explanation of this issue is here: https://fluffy.es/solve-duplicated-cells/. I finally resolved with the following code in the cellForRowAt although the 'reset' code can also be placed in the 'prepareForReuse' function as indicated by Rocky. Setting the 'defaultImage' as seen in code below also helped:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "storyCell", for: indexPath) as! StoryCell

    let story = stories?[indexPath.row]

    //reset to default image

    let defaultURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "jpg")

    do {
        let imageData1 = try Data(contentsOf: defaultURL!)
        let retrievedImage = UIImage(data: imageData1)
        cell.storyImage.image = retrievedImage

    } catch {

        print("Error retrieving defaultImage: \(error)")

    }

    //place saved image in storyImage

    if story?.storyImage.isEmpty == true {

        print("Do nothing")

    } else {

        let path = getDocumentDirectory().appendingPathComponent(story!.storyImage)

        do {
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: path)
            let retrievedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            cell.storyImage.image = retrievedImage

        } catch {

            print("Error retrieving image: \(error)")

        }
    }

    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

Thanks @Rocky for putting me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

[`prepareForReuse`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) is the method which you are looking for.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {        
    super.prepareForReuse()
    // Do your stuff here, like reset image or content of cell for reusing
    self.storyImage.image = nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm getting this error message though when I try to use in my viewController "Method does not override any method from its superclass".

Comment: you need to write this method in your custom cell (called "StoryCell") class.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work for me. I tried to put the following into the prepareForReuse (in the StoryCell), with no success -                                     let path = getDocumentDirectory().appendingPathComponent(story!.storyImage)
        
        do {
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: path)
            let retrievedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
            storyImage.image = retrievedImage
            
        } catch {
            
            print("Error retrieving image: \(error)")
            
        }

Comment: in my StoryCell, I have a function called 'setStory' which sets the title of the cell with:  storyTitleField.text = story.title. I am confused as to why this information remains consistent but the image doesn't when I set the image up in this function.